# Gradle run of app using ControlsFX GridView fails using same VM args as successful Eclipse launch config

Tags: controlsfx, illegalaccessexception

In a non-modular app that uses ControlsFX's GridView (ControlsFX version = '11.1.1', JDK 17), if I run it in an Eclipse launch configuration with the VM arguments settings (in the (x)=Arguments tab) with the same `--add-opens` and `--add-export` arguments as shown in the code snippet below, the app runs just fine.

However, when I invoke `gradle run` from the Gradle Tasks view in Eclipse, with the following `run` block, the result is

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
    class org.controlsfx.control.spreadsheet.GridBase (in unnamed module @0x73a0cead) 
    cannot access class com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager (in module javafx.base) 
    because module javafx.base does not export com.sun.javafx.event to unnamed module @0x73a0cead
```

Here's the `run` block in `build.gradle` for the project.

```
run {
    jvmArgs
    '--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=org.controlsfx.controls \
        --add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED \
        --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls \
        --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED \
        --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls, \
        --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=org.controlsfx.controls \
        --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=org.controlsfx.controls \
        --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls \
        --add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=org.controlsfx.controls'
}
```

the app runs, but the FXML views that include a GridView are empty windows (as expected given the above error).

You can clearly see that the export of `javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event` is specified in the `run` block. Yet the behavior of `gradle run` is different (failure) from that of the launch configuration (success).

Any thoughts on what is causing the failure would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally settled on the following way to set the jvmArgs for the run task. Since I'm doing this in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite, actually), the relevant contents of `build.gradle` are:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
}
```

The `application` block is where one sets `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` (seems like a poor choice to use "Default" since these are custom settings!):

```
application {
    mainClass = ...
    applicationName = ... 
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = jvmArgs
}
```

Gradle Application plugin documentation is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#ex-configure-default-jvm-settings).

In my case, I set the `jvmArgs` value in the `ext` block. Note that I have to include a bunch of other `add-export` and `add-opens` because I use quite a few other controls from the ControlsFX project. See [Using ControlsFX with JDK 9 and above](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/wiki/Using-ControlsFX-with-JDK-9-and-above) for notes on individual controls.

```
ext {
    ...
    jvmArgs = [
        '--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-opens=javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED',
        '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls,',
        '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=org.controlsfx.controls',
        '--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED' 
     ]
    ...
}
```

To use ControlsFX GridView in JavaFX 9+, add the following:

```
'--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=org.controlsfx.controls'
'--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED'
```

which are the last two items in the `jvmArgs` list above.

There's a difference between setting these jvmArgs in an Eclipse launch configuration and executing the `run` task in Gradle: the launch configuration does not seem to require

```
--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
```

That's where I was being thrown off.

Side-note: honestly, I don't know where I got the notion that the `run` block accepted a string for `jvmArgs`.